# Using Update Query for many records at once

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sql-update

the following SQL query I made for a MS Access table is not working. There are several columns with the same SubjectID so this update query would have to update more than one record at a time. Is it even necessary for me to use the group by clause because it is causing problems in ms access.

```
UPDATE PROMIS_LT 
SET [LT_Completion_Metric]  = 0.9
WHERE (SELECT SubjectID FROM PROMIS_LT GROUP BY SubjectID) = 0160110109;
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output? Personally I don't understand well your explanation

Comment: *not working* does not help us. Please be specific. Error? Undesired result? `UPDATE` can update many records at once based on logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant "There are several rows with the same SubjectID" instead of "There are several columns with the same SubjectID". For that you may use below query -

```
UPDATE PROMIS_LT 
   SET [LT_Completion_Metric]  = 0.9
 WHERE SubjectID = 0160110109;
```